# pyautogui.write() not automatically using shift to type characters on non-english keyboard

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate the uploading of a file to a website. Using `selenium` to navigate the website, I got to the point where I get the prompt box to input the filename:

[image: Upload prompt box]

To enter the filename, I thought of using `pyautogui` (but if there is a better way, I'll take it, because at the moment, I'm testing with a headful navigator, but I'm not sure using `pyautogui` will work when I try to use a headless navigator.), like such:

```
import pyautogui 
path = r"C:\path\to_my_file.pdf"
pyautogui.write(path)
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

My problem is that instead of typing the content of `path`, pyautogui types the keyboard keys that correspond to each character. Therefore, I get `C/\path\to8my8file.pdf`, because I have a french keyboard (where numbers are uppercase and special characters like `_` and `:` are lowercase).

Of course, I could make sure that when pyautogui types `:` and `_`, it does what's needed to do `shift` + `/` and `shift` + `8`, but that would be painstaking, and it would have to be done to each specific usecase. I'm sure there is a better, generic way, to type precisely the content of `path`.

Sidenote:

An old SO question had the answers `pyautogui.write('C:\path\to_my_file.pdf', interval=0.1)` or `pyautogui.typewrite("C:\path\to_my_file.pdf", interval=0.1)`. They do not work.

Comment: Support for non-English keyboard layouts has been an [open issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/137) on the pyautogui bug tracker since 2017.  The simplest workaround seems to be to put the text on the clipboard, then automate a Ctrl-V to paste it.

Comment: I thought about it but what a pain...